what is Pādakṛcchra ? and how long does each Pādakṛcchra last for?
what is Pādakṛcchra ? how do we fast for Pādakṛcchra, and can we have coffee or tea or Fruits anything like this or it has to be absolute fast with just water ? and how long does each Pādakṛcchra needs to done ?
